# Powershell Check the folder structure exists or not

Tags: powershell

i am on a task to upgrading a batch file to powershell.. i have to perform a task that need to check if the folder structure is exist or not. if not create it from where it missing. Also need to send a mail using smtp about the status...

```
example: 

D:\folder\folder1\folder2\folder3
E:\folder\folder1\folder2\folder3
E:\folderA\folderB\FolderC\FolderD\FolderE
```

if missing only `FolderC` and Rest create from `FolderC\FolderD\FolderE`

if missing from `FolderB` and rest create from `FolderB\FolderC\FolderD\FolderE`

Comment: Test-Path $path is very helpful to check if path exists

Comment: Thanks for the update Eric, But it will only test the full path and say true or false.. i need to check it for lot of folders and create the structure if missing...

Comment: @rpr so why can't you use that command to check for all the folders you need, and create them if the result is `$false`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will do what you need, including detailed log. Copy-paste it or save alongside with your script as `Test-DirectoryTree.ps1` and use dot-sourcing to load:

```powershell
$ScriptDir = Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
. (Join-Path -Path $ScriptDir -ChildPath 'Test-DirectoryTree.ps1')
```

Usage:

```powershell
# Array of paths to check
$Paths = @(
    'D:\folder\folder1\folder2\folder3',
    'E:\folder\folder1\folder2\folder',
    'E:\folderA\folderB\FolderC\FolderD\FolderE'
)

# Store function output in $Log variable
# W\o "Create" switch  function will only report missing directories
$Log = $Paths | Test-DirectoryTree -Create

# Send email
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer 'mail.company.com' -From 'script@company.com' -To 'admin@company.com' -Subject 'Folder status' -Body $Log
```

`Test-DirectoryTree` function:

```
function Test-DirectoryTree
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string[]]$Paths,

        [switch]$Create
    )

    Begin
    {
        # Set path separator
        $Separator = '\'

        # Init array to hold log
        $Log = @()
    }

    Process
    {
        # For every path in array
        foreach ($Path in $Paths){

            # Init array to store existing paths
            $Tree = @()

            # Split path
            foreach ($Dir in $Path.Split($Separator)){
                # If not first element
                if($Tree)
                {
                    # Build path for current dir to check
                    $CurrDir = Join-Path -Path ($Tree -join $Separator) -ChildPath $Dir
                }
                else # If not first element
                {
                    # Check if root dir exist
                    if(!(Test-Path -LiteralPath $Dir -PathType Container) -and [System.IO.Path]::IsPathRooted($Dir))
                    {
                        Write-Error "Root folder '$Dir' is not valid!"
                        break
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        # Build path for current dir to check
                        $CurrDir = $Dir
                    }
                }

                # If current dir not exist
                if(!(Test-Path -LiteralPath $CurrDir -PathType Container))
                {
                    # Write message to log
                    $Log += "Folder doesn't exist: $CurrDir"

                    # If we asked to create missing dirs
                    if($Create)
                    {
                        # Try to create dir
                        try
                        {
                            New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $CurrDir -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
                            $Log += "Folder created: $CurrDir"
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            $Log += "Failed to create folder: $CurrDir"
                        }
                    }
                }

                # If current dir exist, do nothing and add it to existing paths
                $Tree += $Dir
            }
        }
    }

    End
    {
        # Return log
        return $Log
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be more beautiful but.. Here it goes, there are of course many ways to do this depending on exactly how you want to use it.

```
$SmtpServer = '192.168.1.2' #Replace this with IP adress to your SMTP-server
$Body='' #Two single quotation marks

$path = Read-Host 'Enter Path (Type Exit to quit)'

While ($path -ne 'Exit') {
    IF (Test-Path $path)  {
        $Body += "$path already exists `n" #Adds $path to $Body and breaks line
    }
    ELSE {
        New-Item $path -ItemType directory
        $Body += "$path was created `n" #Adds $path to $Body and breaks line
    }
    $path = Read-Host 'Enter Path (Type Exit to quit)'
}

IF($Body -ne '') {
    Send-Mailmessage -SmtpServer $SmtpServer -Subject "Folder status" -Body $Body
}
```

Comment: That works.. but i need to add this one in between a script with including some more details (output) with mail, So will you help me to separate this tasks... Check the strucure and if missing create it and out put as created so and so else it is already exist.. ??